# Expanding function is surjective

Tags: real-analysis

A continuous function $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$ is said to be expanding if $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge$ |x-y| for every $x,y$ in $\mathbb R^n$.  Prove that any expanding function f is surjective.

It’s easy to prove that f is Injective because f(x)=f(y) gives x=y. But how do I prove that f is surjective?

Comment: Greater to what?

Comment: Greater than or equal to what? $|x-y|$?

Comment: Mod (fx -fy) greater than or equal to Mod (x-y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's compactify $\mathbb{R}^n$ by adding a point at infinity. By our hypothesis, we have $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$$ so setting $f(\infty) = \infty$ yields a continuous function from the compactified space to itself. Now, by the famous invariance of domain theorem for locally Euclidean spaces, $f$ is an open map because it is continuous and injective. On the other hand, since $f$ is a continuous map between compact Hausdorff spaces, it is also a closed map. Thus, the image of $f$ is a nonempty clopen subset of a connected space, so it must be the whole space; $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Thank you so much